# What is the best way to get the Date object for the timestamp 1224642020?

Tags: ruby, datetime, date, time, timestamp

In Ruby, what's the best way to get the `Date` object for the timestamp 1224642020?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby's **Time** class has an *at* method that will do exactly what you need. If you're in Rails, **ActiveSupport** adds a *to_date* method that will convert them all and get you an instance of **Date**.

```
date = Time.at(1224642020).to_date
```

Otherwise, you can convert it by using *strftime* and **Date**'s *parse*

```
date = Date.parse(Time.at(1224642020).strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! I just found that in the [Ruby Documentation for Time](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000251) and decided to go with `Time.at(1224642020).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` for my purposes, but you answered the question exactly as I asked it. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, you're welcome! I'd forgotten that ActiveSupport added on the to_date method, so I've just revised my answer to add an alternative implementation. Luckily, it's exactly what you're doing :)

Comment: In ruby 1.9.2 you don't need ActiveSupport for #to_date.

Comment: @steenslag Are you sure? I tried `Time.now.to_date` on RVM ruby-1.9.2-p0 and got undefined method error.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale You have to require 'date' for #to_date to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Time.at(122...)
```

Not sure how to convert it to Date.

Comment: add `.to_date`. Principle of Least Surprise. Or, as I like to say, principle of Try What Would Make Sense And It Will Most Likely Work.

Comment: Mark, to_date would work in Rails, not sure sure about Ruby 1.9, doesn't work in Ruby 1.8.7.